# full text search vs index to check exactly same text

Tags: mysql, indexing, full-text-search, full-text-indexing, fulltext-index

i have such long text that over bytes limit of index.
The text doesn't have any space. it's combination of things like dbname and table_name.

I will query only check exactly same
`select * from table where column='text'`
or
if i use full text search it may like this.
`select * from table where Match (column) Against(text)`

i don't know which one is best between two options below.
i will use `text_example = '{dbName}/{tableName}'` for explain but in real, it's combination of at least 5types of string.

option1. use full text search

option2. use index
To use index, i have to split text_example to 5types. And then create index each types.

```
create table info (
  dbName text,
  tableName text,
  index dbIdx (dbName),
  index tableIdx (tableName)
);
```

insert query will often.

In this case, which one is best aspects of storage?
how about performance?

or is there any good way to improve select query with such long text?
FYI, i use mysql 8.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Punctuation, such as `/`, separates "words" for the purpose of `FULLTEXT`.
- "dbname/tablename" is not very long text -- that is limited to perhaps 129 characters.  (So, I don't understand where "over bytes limit of index" is coming from.)
- `col = 'text'` checks the whole column; `MATCH..AGAINST` checks "words" in the column.  That is, they do different things.

Please clarify what *the real text is like* and what *the real query is like*.  Then we can advise on `FULLEXT` versus `BTREE`.

Comment: text format like this. 
'{companyName}://{department}/{grade}/{user_id}/{nickname}'

the only case i need is 
`where person='{companyName}://{department}/{grade}/{user_id}/{nickname}'`

in this case which one is best? fulltext vs btree

Comment: If that is always the structure and you are always checking for those 5 things, a 5-column BTree index against 5 _separate_ columns would win.